# How can i check that demo data is loaded or not in a database by code

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can i check that demo data is loaded or not in a database from python code.I know other ways to check , but i need to check it by code.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do is by checking if the XML-ID is loaded :

```py
         # checking if the demo user record exist in database
         # don't forget the put the full qualifying XML-ID (addon_name.xml_id) 
         if not self.env.ref('base.user_demo', raise_if_not_found=False):
               # demo user is not loaded in database
```

Odoo maps the XML-ID with the real ID in database using this model `ir.model.data` if the record is loaded `ref` will return the record from the database else it will `raise an exception` or return `None` based on the second argument `raise_if_not_found` by default it's `True`